# ajax data parameter not retrieved in php file

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, syslog

I am a JAVA developer who is trying for his hands on php. I was trying to retrieve the value of currMonth in php file , passed as parameter in .js file. My log prints everything except what i need

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function() {

var date= new Date();
var currMonth= date.getMonth();
//alert("Month!!:"+currMonth+1);
var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
    "ajax": "php/table.JKBINSR.php",
    "table": "#reminder",
    "data": {
    "currMonth": currMonth
     },
     ......
```

and my php file looks like this

```
<?php

    //echo "Sorry you can't access this page directly";   

openlog("myapp", LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL2);
//syslog(LOG_ERR, {$_POST});
syslog(LOG_ERR, $_POST['currMonth']);
syslog(LOG_ERR, "JAVA ROCKS");
syslog(LOG_ERR, "php sucks");
closelog();
// DataTables PHP library
include( "lib/DataTables.php" );
.......
```

and my log looks like this

```
Feb 10 12:08:25 Wasims-MacBook-Pro.local myapp[1045]: 
Feb 10 12:08:25 Wasims-MacBook-Pro.local myapp[1045]: JAVA ROCKS
Feb 10 12:08:25 Wasims-MacBook-Pro.local myapp[1045]: php sucks
Feb 10 12:08:25 Wasims-MacBook-Pro.local myapp[1045]: 
Feb 10 12:08:25 Wasims-MacBook-Pro.local myapp[1045]: JAVA ROCKS
Feb 10 12:08:25 Wasims-MacBook-Pro.local myapp[1045]: php sucks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know after

```
"ajax": "php/table.JKBINSR.php",
"table": "#reminder",
"data": {
"currMonth": currMonth
 },...
```

if you set method POST try to change to test if is this the problem

```
syslog(LOG_ERR, $_REQUEST['currMonth']);
```